# How to set click listener on a whole ListView (not on the individual items of ListView)?

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I want to set onClickListener() on the whole layout space of ListView i.e. if I click anywhere on layout area of a ListView, a specific task should be performed. How can I accomplish that in Android using java?

Notice that I do not want onItemClickListener(), tapping anywhere on the screen should perform the task.

ChatActivity.java

```
chatList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.chat_list);


        adapter = new ChatMessageAdapter(ChatActivity.this, tempList);

        chatList.setAdapter(adapter);

        chatList.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // code here
                return false;
            }
        });
```

activity_chat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="18dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Person 1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Person 2"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/chat_list"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this sample:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

final private static float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 10;
float fingerDownX, fingerDownY;

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ArrayList<String> datalist = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        datalist.add("Item " + i);
    }
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datalist);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            float fingerX = motionEvent.getX();
            float fingerY = motionEvent.getY();
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                fingerDownX = fingerX;
                fingerDownY = fingerY;
            }
            if((motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)&&
                    (Math.abs(fingerDownX - fingerX) < TOUCH_TOLERANCE)&&
                    (Math.abs(fingerDownY - fingerY) < TOUCH_TOLERANCE)){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "List Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

why you don't perform a `onClickListener()` on the parent layout of your `listview` ?

did you even try adding `setOnTouchListener()` or `setOnClickListener` the listview ?

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

in your java side

```
LinearLayout listlayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout_list);
listlayout.setClickable(true);

listlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
 {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v)
    {
    /// do your stuff here 
    }
  });
```

Comment: Tried but all in vain :(

Comment: Yes, I tried setOnTouchListener() to the ListView but it's not responding the way I want. It will be a great help if you could tell me about how to use that on just a single click event and do nothing on other types of touch events.

Comment: please edit your question and  add your code  xml and java

Comment: is your listview well generated in the layout ? it seems like it's not there

Comment: Yes, ListView is working perfectly. Scroll to the end of XML file if you are unable to find that :)

Comment: also you are retruning false in your onTouchListener

Comment: I know nothing about onTouchListener. The code I provided loads the whole list in just a single click but I want to load just one item in a single click. It will be helpful if you could provide the code that I should use inside the onTouchListener.

Comment: i don't undersant , do you want a click on the listview or on the item of the listview ?

Comment: I want a click on the whole ListView, as described in the question.

Comment: Whenever I touch anywhere on the screen, a new item should be added to the adapter view.

Comment: I've tried almost everything with setOnClickListener() which seems legit to me, but anything is not working. Stack Overflow is my last hope :(

Comment: If you change your listView into recyclerview, setting clicklisener on parent viewgroup works.